# using special characters in mysql query throws exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql

this is mysqlquery

```
SELECT course_id
FROM course_master
WHERE year_id = '6'
AND course_name = ''What is Test?': Perspectives'
```

When i run the query it throws a syntax error because of special characters problem.Iam using   mysql_escape_string to escape but it is not working.How to escape these characters

Comment: now I am interested in how you escape that string... could you provide that code?

Comment: please show the actual PHP code; we can't give you accurate help without it.

Comment: Hi the actual code is                                                                         $sql = "select course_id from course_master where year_id='".$year."' and course_name='".$this->sanitiseData($course_name)."'"; 
$course_id =  $this->_dbAdapter->fetchOne($sql);


public function sanitiseData($data) 
{ 
$data = mysql_escape_string($data); 
return $data; 
}

Answer (score 1):

> I am using mysql_escape_string to escape but it is not working.

You are using it wrong. You have to format string values only, not whole query

```
// here are your variables
$year = 6;
$name = "'What is Test?': Perspectives";

// let's format them
$year = intval($year);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

// and then insert in a query
$sql  = "SELECT course_id FROM course_master 
         WHERE year_id = $year AND course_name = '$name'";
```

Comment: Hi Iam Using in this way but not working $sql = "select course_id from course_master where year_id='".$year."' and course_name='".$this->sanitiseData($module_name)."'"; public function sanitiseData($data)
 {
  $data =  mysql_escape_string($data);
  return $data;
 }

Answer (score 0):

when executing a query and a value has single quotes, double the single quotes so won't get an error.

```
SELECT course_id
FROM course_master
WHERE year_id = '6'
AND course_name = '''What is Test?'': Perspectives'
```

but if you are doing it on PHP, use `PreparedStatement` on that. This will also prevent from  `SQL Injection`. The article below will show you how to use `PHP Extensions.`

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT course_id
FROM course_master
WHERE year_id = 6
AND course_name = '''What is Test?'': Perspectives'
```

or use escaping -

```
SELECT course_id
FROM course_master
WHERE year_id = 6
AND course_name = '\'What is Test?\': Perspectives'
```